# Python multiprocessing imaplib throws error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, imaplib

I have the following piece of code in which I am trying to fetch mails from different directories of a mailbox concurrently. However, it is showing the folloing problem. Have attached the shortened stacktrace.

```
import multiprocessing as mlp
import imaplib as impl

def somefunc(dirc):
    mail.select(dirc)
    result, data = mail.uid("search", None, "All")
    uids = data[0].split()
    print dirc
    for mail_id in uids:
       result, data = mail.uid("fetch", mail_id, "(RFC822)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mail = impl.IMAP4_SSL("somedomain")
    mail.login("username","password")

    jobs = []
    p1 = mlp.Process(target = somefunc, args = ("INBOX",))
    jobs.append(p1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = mlp.Process(target = somefunc, args = ("Sent",))
    jobs.append(p2)
    p2.start()
    for i in jobs:
        i.join()
```

It throws error:

```
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
........
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 859, in _command
    raise self.abort('socket error: %s' % val)
abort: socket error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, mailbox)
........
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Is it not possible to do imap connection concurrently???

Thanks... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are having problems because you are attempting to share the mail socket connection object across processes. Instead, try having each process create its connection:

```
import multiprocessing as mlp
import imaplib as impl

def somefunc(domain, name, password, dirc):
    mail = impl.IMAP4_SSL(domain)
    mail.login(name, password)
    mail.select(dirc)
    result, data = mail.uid("search", None, "All")
    uids = data[0].split()
    print dirc
    for mail_id in uids:
       result, data = mail.uid("fetch", mail_id, "(RFC822)")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []

    for box in ("INBOX", "Sent"):
        p = mlp.Process(
                target = somefunc, 
                args = ("somedomain", "username", "password", box)
            )
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()

    for i in jobs:
        i.join()
```

Comment: Thanks man, I just figured it out and have already posted the UPDATE... thanks for the prompt reply... :)

Comment: Looks exactly like what I posted in my answer, 20 minutes before your update :-) And my answer is directed at needing unique connections per process because of the sockets. It really has nothing to do with wanting to ready different mailbox directories.

Comment: Yeah I see that your language is more recommended for people... pleased... :)

Comment: Well my point was that if my answer was the one that addressed your problem, usually what you do is checkmark it as answered instead of taking it and adding it to your question and saying "enjoy". Just sayin...

Comment: Yeah I got that and it's done... new here so still fumbling I guess... and btw while I added my answer I hadn't seen your reply (my bad). So sorry for the redundancy...

Comment: Hah, no worries. I realize you are new to the site. I guess your page didn't refresh for 20 minutes or something. Anyways, thanks!